# Highcharts remove x-axis label solid line

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way I can remove the line that appears above the x-axis labels?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily hide the X axis while keeping its labels by changing `xAxis.lineWidth` to 0.

**Example:**

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }]
})
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pb736w8c/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.lineWidth